# Getting test runner to work with Gallio from Nuget

Tags: nuget, mbunit, gallio, testdriven.net

I think I'm missing something here. I installed [Tesdriven](http://www.testdriven.net/) and then [Gallio](http://gallio.org/downloads.aspx) (third link from top - Gallio 3.5 x64 installer)

Then I installed the [mbunit dlls from Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/mbunit) because I didn't want to include a dll from my hard drive as it makes it difficult for the project to be ported to other machines..

However, when I try to run a sample test, testrunner insists that I reference the dlls from my hard disk.. the actual error message is this:

```
It looks like you're trying to execute a Gallio/MbUnit unit test.

For Gallio v3.0.6 build 787 / Gallio v3.1 build 313 or above (recommended):
Please ensure that the directory containing your 'MbUnit.dll' reference also contains Gallio's
test runner files ('MbUnit.dll.tdnet', 'TDNet\Gallio.TDNetRunner.dll', 'Gallio.dll' etc.)

For earlier versions:
You need to install Gallio (after TestDriven.Net) using its MSI installer.

You can find Gallio downloads and support here:
http://www.gallio.org/
```

So, is there a way to get testrunner to run the tests with just nuget packages, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently nuget gallery has only 3.3.1 version of mbunit package, and you installed Gallio v3.4. It's very annoying limitation of gallio and mbunit. In order to use nuget package you have to downgrade Gallio on your machine to [v3.3.1](http://mb-unit.googlecode.com/files/GallioBundle-3.3.458.0-Setup-x64.msi). Better solution it's mail to gallio/mbunit team and ask to upload nuget package with latest release or make it by yourself.

Comment: Hi, That worked!! Thanks so much, though, I have a question. How did you figure out that the versions were different and I needed the same versions for it to run smoothly, please?

Comment: We use mbunit at my job, and from time to time face with problem of different versions of installed gallio and dlls.

Comment: I occasionally use MbUnit at work and I just ran into this problem as well. Your answer put an end to 3 hours of smacking my head against the desk